# Admin form select value from dropdown

Tags: forms, adminform

Model/Nic.php contains

```
public function toOptionArray()
         {

          $nicCollection = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->getCollection();

          $nicarray = array(array('value'=>-1, 'label'=>'Please Select'));

          foreach ($nicCollection as $nicList){

                $nicarray[] = array('value'=>$nicList['nic_id']._.$nicList['nic_cost'],'label'=>$nicList['nic_name']);
          }

          return $nicarray;

        }
```

I have added a dropdown using `toOptionArray` in admin form using below code

```
    protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
      $nicModel = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->load($id);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('nic_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic Information')));


      //Check if value selected from dropdown
        $Id = Mage::registry('nic_data')->getId();
        if($Id != ''){
        $nicId = Mage::registry('nic_data')->getNicId();
        $form->addValues(array('nic_id' => $nicId));
        }


      $fieldset->addField('nic_id', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'values'    => Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->toOptionArray(),
          'name'      => 'nic_id',
      ));


      if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCoffeecomponentsData() )
      {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCoffeecomponentsData());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCofeecomponentsData(null);
      } elseif ( Mage::registry('nic_data') ) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('nic_data')->getData());
      }

      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
```

Which outputs

```
<select name="nic_id" id="nic_id">
<option value="-1">Please Select</option>
<option value="1_3.4">America</option>
<option value="2_2.3">China</option>
<option value="3_4.5">India</option>
<option value="4_2.5">Japan</option>
</select>
```

Here the value for **China** is `2` and its country cost value is `2.3` which has been split and then saved into DB as `nic_id = 2` and `nic_cost = 2.3`

Now while editing the same record I am not able to select the value China in dropdown as the value fetched form Model is like `2_2.3`.

Also before add field I have used this code to make it selected, but somehow its not working

```
$Id = Mage::registry('nic_data')->getId();
if($Id != ''){
$nicId = Mage::registry('nic_data')->getNicId();
$form->addValues(array('nic_id' => $nicId ));
}
```

How can make it make it selected ?

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 2):

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
$form_data = new Varien_Object();

$form = new Varien_Data_Form();
$this->setForm($form);
....

if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getXyzData() )
{
    $form_data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getXyzData();
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setXyzData(null);
} 
else if ( Mage::registry('xyz_data') ) {
    $form_data = Mage::registry('xyz_data');  
}

$catId = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getCatId();   // it has value 4

if( empty($form_data->getData('category_id')) ){
    $form_data->setData('category_id', $catId);
}

$fieldset->addField('category_id', 'select', array(
  'label' => Mage::helper('lookbook')->__('Lookbook'),
  'name' => 'category_id[]',
  'values' => $categoryArray,            
 'disabled' => true
));
```

....

```
$form->setValues($form_data);

$this->setForm($form);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
      $nicModel = Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->load($id);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('nic_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic Information')));

      $fieldset->addField('nic_id', 'select', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('nic')->__('Nic'),
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'values'    => Mage::getModel('nic/nic')->toOptionArray(),
          'name'      => 'nic_id',
      ));


      if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCoffeecomponentsData() )
      {
          $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getCoffeecomponentsData());
          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setCofeecomponentsData(null);
      } elseif ( Mage::registry('nic_data') ) {
          $form->setValues(Mage::registry('nic_data')->getData());
      }

      return parent::_prepareForm();
  }
```

Comment: I have the same code. What is the change ?

Comment: can you post whole code of the form please.

Comment: Check the edited code now

Comment: now use the edited code.i had removed the form->add value code then the above code is working for me.you can try it.

Comment: setValue will do the work for you.

Comment: What did you changed ?

Comment: the code after this //Check if value selected from dropdown.

Comment: NO its not working. Perhaps you should ready my question completely